# Save list to a file, add another list to the same file, and load later, on google colab

Tags: python, list, save, google-colaboratory

Can somebody kindly recommend a good way of saving a list to a file, add another list to the same file, and load all the saved lists in that file later, on google colab?

Answer (score 0):

```
lists_to_write = ['losses', 'time']
data = {listname: globals()[listname] for listname in lists_to_write}

with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=2)
```

Here *lists_to_write* contains names of the lists you want to store in a file with path as *file_path*

You can then load the file like this:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```